# Find Duplicate Array By Caption without using multiple loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of objects i.e

```
[
 {  
   caption:"Name1"
    dataField:"0"
    dataType:"string"
    objKey:"0"
  },
  {
    caption:"Name2"
    dataField:"0"
    dataType:"string"
    objKey:"0"
  },
  {
    caption:"Name1"
    dataField:"0"
    dataType:"string"
    objKey:"0"
  }
```

]

I want to get an Array which is duplicate by the caption. So here my Output which I want Would be

```
{    
     caption:"Name1"
     dataField:"0"
     dataType:"string"
     objKey:"0"
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the lodash filter method:  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter